# SP2013: Scrollbar is not working in chrome

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a portal in SP2013. In IE everything is working fine, but in Chrome the scrollbar is not working. I have googled and it seems to be a known problem. But I see only solutions for SP2010. How can I fix this problem for SP2013?

Comment: Never had this problem with 2013, only 2010. Are you using a custom master page? Then the problem lays in the master page.

Comment: yes I am using a custom masterpage. so there is some differance between the Original masterpage and my custom masterpage.

Comment: If I where you I would look over those differences to see which one is causing the problems